# Why can't I import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have Maven dependencies `spark-sql_2.1.0`and `spark-hive_2.1.0`. However, when I am trying to `import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`, there is an error. But importing 
`org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext` is OK, there is no errors. Why?

Comment: what type of error you're getting ? this works for me just fine

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: @T.Gawęda  I am using Java

Comment: @JasonShu Ok so my answer is correct :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DataFrame has become a `type DataFrame = Dataset[Row]` in Spark 2.x. Java doesn't have type aliases, so it's not available in Java. You should now use the new type `Dataset<Row>`, so import both `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` and `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Comment: @JasonShu You should also use SparkSession in Spark 2.x :)

Comment: Yes,my spark is 2.x.And the return type of sqlContext.read is DataFrame.So there will be mistakes

Answer (score 5):

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

works for `scala` and not for `java` as there is no library developed for `java`. You can use `dataSet` as explained in [Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

You can import the following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
```

and use them as

```
Dataset<Row> peopleDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
```

Or

```
Dataset<Row> peopleDF = spark.createDataFrame(peopleRDD, Person.class);
```

Or

```
Dataset<Row> usersDF = spark.read().load("examples/src/main/resources/users.parquet");
```

Comment: That is true.But if I got a DataFrame,for example, sqlContext.read().What should I do?

Comment: you can use `Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read.csv("location")`. :) it should be fine. did you try ?

Comment: Yes,it works.But when it comes to sqlContext.read.json,it failed.

Comment: did you see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets